# Struts2 validation expression sample

Tags: struts2

What does this `[D][C][M])[-]*[a-zA-z0-9]*$` mean? What do `*`,`^`,`$` `[-]` all mean? Please explain.

Comment: The sample looks a little incomplete to me... is there more before it?

Answer (score 0):

That looks like part of a [regular expression validator](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/regex-validator.html) -

- `*` - match the previous item 0 or more times
- `^` - the beginning of a line
- `$` - the end of a line
- `[-]` - the character class that contains "-"
- `[1-5]` - the character class that contains the range of "1" to "5" inclusive
- `[a-z]` - the character class that contains the range of "a" to "z" inclusive

`[D][C][M])[-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]*$`:

- `[D][C][M])` - some capture group ending with the characters "DCM"
- `[-]*` - 0 or more "-"s
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]*$` -  0 or more alphanumeric characters at the end of the line